# How to prevent caret from jumping over codeblock

Tags: javascript, html, css, quill

In my rich-text editor implemented by Quill.js I've noticed, that when I'm navigating through the document by keyboard's arrows, the caret enters the code-block only from above. When I'm trying to enter codeblock from the bottom, caret always jumps over codeblock.

The problem is, that if the content of the codeblock (the `<pre>` element) ends with `\n`, the caret won't enter the element from bottom, but jumps over. If the content ends with anything but `\n`, caret enters the element as expected. This behaviour happens in Chrome and Safari, the Firefox works.

I can't do anything with the `\n` at the end of the content, because Quill will add it there itself as a way how it treats its content.

Is this behaviour expected and reasonable? Can somebody please explain what is going on and how to navigate the caret to the codeblock even from bottom?

[image: care jumping over codeblock]

```css
.cont {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

pre {
  background-color: #EBECED;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont" contenteditable="true">
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <pre spellcheck="false">
  content ends with space
    
    
  </pre>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
</div>


<div class="cont" contenteditable="true">
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <pre spellcheck="false">
  content ends with new line
    
    
    
</pre>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
</div>
```